# Loading animated images to start from the beginning of animation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, animated-gif, image-rotation

This is a follow on from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153520/rotating-divs-using-jquery) which does exactly what I need it to do except there's a problem.

I am rotating images using divs which just show and hide a div every 5 seconds using setInterval.

The problem with this approach is that I am loading animated gif files so even when the next image switches, it becomes messy because the images have been there all along and been animating.

So, what happens is that image1(div1) will start fresh with its animation, it will fade out and image2(div2) will show but the animation would have already started when it was invisible.

What I need is a method of loading these images afresh so that the animation begins from the start again when the next div fades in. The only way to do this with Gifs is to actually load them from the cache and this is the solution I need using jQuery.

Here's what I have:

```
var images = new Array ('.advert1', '.advert2');
var index = 0;

function rotateImage()
{

$(images[index]).fadeOut('fast', function()
{
   index++;
   if (index == images.length)
       {
           index = 0;
       }
   $(images[index]).fadeIn('fast');
 });
}

setInterval (rotateImage, 5000);
```

And in my html:

```
<div>
    <div class="advert1"><img id="myImage" src="advert1.gif" alt="image test" /></div>
    <div class="advert2"><img src="advert2.gif" alt="image test" /></div>
</div>
```

Now what I need is to be able to make it "seem" as though the images are loaded fresh every time so that when the div fades in, the animation begins from the start.

Anyone know how I can crack this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest using non-animated gifs to start with, and loading the animated gif to replace them. I can't put a demo together from where I am, but it seems an easier approach.

Comment: Hi David. To throw another spanner in the works! I have no control over the gifs as they are animated adverts from our clients. :(

Answer (score 2):

did you tried to reload image by setting src again:

```
var img = $(images[index] img);
//this should reset animation (but without proper caching it could be a pain)
img.attr(src,img.attr(src));
$(images[index]).fadeIn('fast');
```

Comment: Good idea; so much simpler than my own suggestion/comment to the question. +1 =)

Answer (score 0):

If you reload the src property, the gif reload

```
var images = new Array ('.advert1', '.advert2');
var index = 0;

function rotateImage()
{

$(images[index]).fadeOut('fast', function()
{
   index++;
   if (index == images.length)
       {
           index = 0;
       }
   $(images[index]).get(0).src=$(images[index]).get(0).src;
   $(images[index]).fadeIn('fast');
 });
}

setInterval (rotateImage, 5000);
```